# Disable network on remastered Ubuntu 13.04 Live-CD except for localhost

Tags: networking, live-usb, live-cd

I have remastered a Ubuntu 13.04 Live-CD for software presentations. During boot, it tries to find a network connection for several minutes (but fails in the end). Maybe it does not detect my network card properly (MacBook Pro). For the live system I don't need an internet connection. Only access to localhost is important.

How do I prevent the system from configuring the network/internet connection while still preserving access to localhost?

If I can not turn this off, is it possible to reduce the timeout for this configuration process?

**EDIT:** I forgot to say that I used a minimal Ubuntu 13.04 with command line only. Hence, no GUI components are responsible for the delay.

**EDIT 2:** The `/etc/network/interfaces` of the Live-DVD before remastering is

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by editing `/etc/init/failsafe.conf`, which contained the messages and the delays:

```
# failsafe

description "Failsafe Boot Delay"
author "Clint Byrum <clint@ubuntu.com>"

start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo
stop on static-network-up or starting rc-sysinit

emits failsafe-boot

console output

script
    # Determine if plymouth is available
    if [ -x /bin/plymouth ] && /bin/plymouth --ping ; then
        PLYMOUTH=/bin/plymouth
    else
        PLYMOUTH=":"
    fi

    # The point here is to wait for 2 minutes before forcibly booting 
    # the system. Anything that is in an "or" condition with 'started 
    # failsafe' in rc-sysinit deserves consideration for mentioning in
    # these messages. currently only static-network-up counts for that.
    sleep 20

    # Plymouth errors should not stop the script because we *must* reach
    # the end of this script to avoid letting the system spin forever
    # waiting on it to start.
    $PLYMOUTH message --text="Waiting for network configuration..." || :
    sleep 40

    $PLYMOUTH message --text="Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration..." || :
    sleep 59

    $PLYMOUTH message --text="Booting system without full network configuration..." || :

    # give user 1 second to see this message since plymouth will go
    # away as soon as failsafe starts.
    sleep 1
    exec initctl emit --no-wait failsafe-boot
end script

post-start exec logger -t 'failsafe' -p daemon.warning "Failsafe of 120 seconds reached."
```

Just replace the `xx` in `sleep xx` with a small value. It might also be possible to remove the sleep commands. This does not necessarily disable the network interfaces, but reduces the time for the system trying to find a connection.

Comment: This general problem/solution is a recurring theme among Ubuntu users who are finding themselves confronted with a system that is *purposely* not configuring an ethernet device on startup, yet this failsafe task assumes one *must* be present. This is a faulty assumption on the part of failsafe. It sure seems to me the real solution is to alter the conditions of failsafe to prevent this behavior - to enforce the network setup is an, ahem, rather Microsoftian approach to system management..

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is searching for a wireless access point. Normally, Network Manager will not look for an ethernet connection if it can't detect a cable. I suggest you determine the wireless driver from the terminal command:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

In many MacBooks, the driver will show as b43-pci-bridge. If this is your case, you actually want b43. Blacklist the wireless driver you found:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add a new line at the end:

```
blacklist driver
```

...where *driver* is the wireless driver you found in lshw.

Then remaster.

Comment: The problem might occur on other systems, too. Is there a way to blacklist all network devices?

Comment: In that instance, I think a more practical solution is to remove Network Manager: sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manage* and then remaster.

Comment: No `network-manage*` packages are installed since I used a minimal, command line based system. Any suggestions?

Comment: If Network Manager is not present, then interfaces look for their connections based on entries in /etc/network/interfaces. What does yours contain? I suggest you remove everything except the loopback entries.